# Can't run Dwarf Fortress

Tags: gnome, games

When executing Dwarf fortress, comes up with this error.
I'm quite new to ubuntu and I could do with some help.

```
No value set for `/desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec'
No value set for `/desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec_arg'
xdg-terminal: configured terminal program '' not found or not executable
```

I am pretty sure this isn't to do with libraries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run Dwarf Fortress?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226613/how-do-i-run-dwarf-fortress)

Comment: No completely different problem, that is to do with directories and libraries, unless I'm mistaken this is something else

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like you hit the same problem as I did with [the "Lazy Newb Pack for Linux"](https://github.com/Lazy-Newb-Pack/Lazy-Newb-Pack-Linux). After some digging it turns out that repository includes a fairly old version of [PyLNP](https://bitbucket.org/PeridexisErrant/python-lnp) which contains a broken `xdg-terminal` script. (Worse still the pack additionally contains a redundant copy of `xdg-terminal` which is never used as the release bundles a binary copy of PyLNP!)

Maybe you're like me and simply wanted to play the game. If so you can pretty much install some dependencies, [download the original game](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/), extract it and run the thing. Problem with that is that you're left with ASCII art instead of a nice graphical tileset.

I spent an embarrassing amount of time this evening learning about the various moving parts and I finally came up with some (fairly) simple installation instructions: https://gist.github.com/kzar/341cbb885896e082acb6